# Scaling in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I'm just getting started with Illustrator. I've created some artwork I like. I want to press it now for the web. If I click "Save for web", change the size to something small like 30x100 (px) it's all pixelated. If I save it huge and then scale down in a different program (like Preview on Mac), I get a smooth scale effect.

Can I achieve this direct in Illustrator (I'm using CS6 Creative Cloud).

Comment: What size is the original artwork? Can you simply duplicate the artwork in Illustrator, scale it to whatever size you need, then save for web?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have CS6, but in CS4 I can't replicate this behavior without messing with the anti-alias option in the save for web dialogue.

Could it be that you just have it unticked for some reason?

Well, I even did you a graphic to illustrate where it all was, but because I don't have enough points on this particular stack exchange yet it won't let me attach it...

Comment: If you upload it to http://imgur.com/ and then drop the URL as plain text into your answer, people can see it and either upvote you the rep or edit the image in for you.

Answer (score 1):

When designing for web in Illustrator it's best to turn on pixel preview (in the View menu) and work in one of two ways:

1. Work at the final pixel dimension you'll need
2. Create your art at any size and then scale a copy to the size you need for export